# How to get names of objects within object? (JSON)

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to figure out (using json-simple) how to get the name of an object within an object. For example:

```
{ { "objs": { "obj1": "blah", "obj2": "blah" } } }
```

I would like to get the value `obj1` and `obj2` (as they're the names of the objects, which is what I want). How would I do this with JSON-Simple and Java and put them into a String[]?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I haven't used the library before, but why not `getJsonObject("objs").getString("obj1")`?

Comment: @Lewis probably because this use case is already covered by APIs docs, tutorials, FAQ etc., and thus it doesn't show any real research effort?

Comment: Just to let you know, I searched up quite a bit, and couldn't find my answer. That's why I came here.

Comment: @Lewis https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples (as supplied by Davo, and clearly referenced on https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) - if your "quite a bit" doesn't cover looking up the original documentation, then instead of asking questions on SO you should learn how to use docs properly... otherwise you're risking [StackSyndrome](http://www.theunrealtimes.com/2015/01/07/govt-bans-stackoverflow-com-developer-takes-6-hours-to-swap-2-variables/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **org.json** library.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20150729</version>
</dependency>
```

> jar download: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Or **google gson** library

*Maven dependency*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

> jar download: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.4

**Org json Example**:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{ 'objs': { 'obj1': 'blah', 'obj2': 'blah' } } ");

JSONObject objs = jsonObject.getJSONObject("objs");

String obj1 = objs.getString("obj1");
String obj2 = objs.getString("obj1");

System.out.println(obj1);
System.out.println(obj2);
```

**Google gson Example**

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

.

```
JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();

JsonObject object=(JsonObject)parser.parse("{ 'objs': { 'obj1': 'blah', 'obj2': 'blah' } } ");

JsonObject objs2 = object.get("objs").getAsJsonObject();

String value1=objs2.get("obj1").getAsString();
String value2=objs2.get("obj2").getAsString();

System.out.println(value1);
System.out.println(value2);
```

**JSON simple is an old library** that is not maintained anymore, last release was on 2012.  `google gson` and `org json` last releases were on 2015, anyway, if you want to use the old library, take a look to the documentation:

> https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples